# Using select_related to get related_name objects

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

I've been searching for a while now for a solution to my problem, but I can't seem to figure this out.

So I have two models:

```
class Messages(models.Model):
    _db = 'somedb'
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    text = models.TextField()

class MessageTags(models.Model):
    _db = 'somedb'
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    text = models.TextField()
    tag = models.ForeignKey(Tag)
    message = models.ForeignKey(Messages, related_name='tags')
```

I am able to query the tags for a given message using the following call:
`test = Messages.get(id=234124).tags.all()`
^ returns a list of MessageTags

What I would like to do, is to in theory perform a left join, where I get all the messages for a certain criteria with the associated MessageTags objects.  I was pointed in the direction of using select_related, but I cannot get anything to work.

How do I get the list of messages, with the MessageTags as an attribute of each as .tags (or anything else..)

Thank you!!

Comment: Have you tried `Messages.get(id=234124).tags.filter(criteria...)` ?

Comment: What exactly didn't work out with `select_related`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't believe `select_related` is going to be able to perform in the method you're looking for. But really, neither would a left join.

Think of it this way: One message could have 5 tags. If you do a join, you will get 5 rows in your result set for that one message, which makes it look like 5 messages.

Now, as you noted, you can reference `.tags.all()` on an individual message and get all of the MessageTags associated with that Message. If I understand your case correctly, this is actually what you're looking for.

Of course, if you're trying to optimize the number of queries executed, I would recommend looking at `prefetch_related`. Here is an example of how you could use this:

```
messages = Messages.objects.filter(text__icontains='foobar').prefetch_related('tags')
for message in messages:
    for tag in message.tags.all():
        print('Message id', message.id, '- tag', tag.text)
```

That should execute 2 queries:

1. Retrieve your filtered listed of messages
2. Retrieve all tags related to those messages

Comment: ah thank you so much! I knew there was something I was missing, and since I can't left join/group concat, this is the next best thing!