# multiple joins on django queryset

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models, django-views, django-queryset

For the below sample schema

```
    # schema sameple
    
    class A(models.Model):
        n = models.ForeignKey(N, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        d = models.ForeignKey(D, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    
    class N(models.Model):
        id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, editable=False)
        d = models.ForeignKey(D, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    
    class D(models.Model):
        dsid = models.CharField(max_length=255, primary_key=True)
    
    class P(models.Model):
        id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, editable=False)
        name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
        n = models.ForeignKey(N, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    
    # raw query for the result I want
    
    # SELECT P.name
    # FROM P, N, A
    # WHERE (P.n_id = N.id
    #     AND A.n_id = N.id
    #     AND A.d_id = \'MY_DSID\'
    #     AND P.name = \'MY_NAME\')
```

What am I trying to achieve?

Well, I’m trying to find a way somehow be able to write a single queryset which does the same as what the above raw query does. So far I was able to do it by writing two queryset, and use the result from one queryset and then using that queryset I wrote the second one, to get the final DB records. However that’s 2 hits to the DB, and I want to optimize it by just doing everything in one DB hit.

What will be the queryset for this kinda raw query ? or is there a better way to do it ?

Above code is here https://dpaste.org/DZg2

Answer (score 0):

You can archive it using `related_name` attribute and functions like `select_related` and `prefetch_related`.

Assuming the related name for each model will be the model's name and `_items`, but it is better to have proper model names and then provided meaningful related names. Related name is how you access the model in backward.

This way, you can use this query to get all models in a single DB hit:

```py
A.objects.all().select_related("n", "d", "n__d").prefetch_related("n__p_items")
```

I edited the code in the [pasted site](https://dpaste.org/GspA#L3,9,13,17,21,22,23,25,28), however, it will expire soon.

Comment: thank you for the solution however, `select_related` is one query while `prefetch_related` is two, so the former is faster. I want to do it in one hit to the DB.

Comment: Yes, Django doesn't support selecting more than 1 table in a query, it can only make joins and select_related creates a join statement. Unless you change relationship between models, the only way might be using a `raw` function and execute your own SQL code. I'm not sure how its result will be parsed, just make it in the django shell and check for the result.

Comment: This is another question that is related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33224827/using-select-related-to-get-related-name-objects

Comment: I did write a raw SQL and it’s mentioned in the question above, it works. I was wondering if there was a way in django QuerySet which I can leverage instead of shelling out SQL query which isn’t the best solution in terms of maintainablility. .

Comment: No, in terms of model relations, if there is no direct relation to a model, Django ORM cannot query them together. Reverse connections are queries using the prefetch function and it is done in a secondary query. So, there is no way for Django ORM to have multiple tables in the SELECT query, only joins.

Comment: I’m ok with single table in SELECT but I want that to happen based upon the WHERE conditions which span over multi tables. Will that be doable in a single hit to DB ? To explain it, I modified the sample RAW query in my question at the top, please see.

Comment: Your query still contains `FROM P, N, A` that will select 3 tables to work with. This is the part that Django cannot do using Querysets directly.

Comment: got it, that answers my question then. *sigh* thank you!